# is this **vector of *vectors correct ?, and how can I print out all values in all vectors

Tags: c++, vector

In short, is this definition of vector of vectors correct ?

```
// Create a dynamic vector which contain another 3 vectors 
vector<int> **list = new vector<int>*[3]();
// Create and initialize vectors that related to a vector  
for (unsigned short i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    list[i] = new vector<int>(i);
}
```

Now I want print out all elements in all vectors.

```
for (unsigned short i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (unsigned short io = 0; io < 3; io++) {
        cout << list[i]->at(io) << endl;
    }
    cout << "/n";
}
```

But the following runtime error appears.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use a vector of vectors instead of a dynamic array of vectors?

Comment: I have never seen any legitimate need to use a pointer to vector

Comment: Arrays of pointers to vectors? Far too complicated.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is wrong:

```
// Create a dynamic vector which contain another 3 vectors 
vector<int> **list = new vector<int>*[3]();
```

No, this create an array of 3 pointers to `vector<int>*`.

```
// Create and initialize vectors that related to a vector  
for (unsigned short i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    list[i] = new vector<int>(i);
}
```

Yes, but... Do you really want your first vector to have a size of `0`, your second a size of `1`, ...?

```
cout << list[i]->at(io) << endl;
```

You did initialize `list[i]`, which is a `vector<int>*`, so `list[i]->at` is correct but since your first vector a size `0` this code fails.

What you probably want is<sup>*</sup>:

```
vector<vector<int>> list(3, vector<int>(3));
```

Which initialize a `vector` containing 3 `vector<int>`, each one containing 3 int (a 3x3 matrix).

<sup>*</sup> Use `vector< vector<int> >` if you use c++03.

Then you can iterate (and get only `0`  as output since you did not initialize it to anything else):

```
for (unsigned short i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (unsigned short io = 0; io < 3; io++) {
        cout << list[i][io] << endl;
    }
    cout << "/n"; // Should be "\n"
}
```

Or better with a range-based loop (c++11):

```
for (auto const &row: list) {
    for (auto const &val: row) {
        cout << val << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: `int val` is shorter than `auto val`. Why obscure the readability?

Comment: @Chiel `auto` isn't just about *shorter* code. I for one wonder why isn't it `auto const&` in this case.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz. I agree, but why would you write auto val in this case while it is obvious that it is about an `int`?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I did not add the `&` myself, but you're right that one should use `auto const&`.

Comment: @Chiel because then that code would work for any type, not just `int`, without any change? Good code should respond well to change. Why would you limit it unnecessarily?

Comment: Thank you, but I think this is stored in the stack not in the heap as I want.

Comment: @LionKing that's not how it works. Do a `sizeof(std::vector<std::vector<int>>)` and you'll see how many bytes are used on the "stack". (and the answer is, of course, a constant size, independent on the size of the vector)